# Flask website not launching, even with default code copied from documentation

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have been coding in flask for a few days now, and I am getting into making my own websites. I am not sure what happened though, because when I woke up today flask did not work any more. I then tried running the default code found in the flask documentation, which also did not work. The console showed:

```
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

On going to the normal url given, the website displayed:

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Post the code you're trying to run, or enough of it demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Check your logs to find the error.

Comment: The code is just the default code on the flask documentation

Comment: How you run the app? `flask run` or `python app.py`? Please post the code, you may have a typo or something similar in the code.

Comment: The code is:
from flask import Flask app = Flask(name) @app.route('/') def hello(): return "Hello World!" if name == 'main': app.run(debug=True) 
I run the 'python app.py' command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to my question. It turns out that I just had to restart my computer. I presume that some sort of phantom process was running in the background that was killed when I restarted.
I hope this helps someone else, and sorry for any wasted time.

Answer (score 0):

Your flask app debug mode if OFF right now. Please enable it and run. Then you can debug the real issues. You can enable the debug mode like this.

```
app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: I have done this, the website says the same thing and the console now says
````
* Serving Flask app "main" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with windowsapi reloader
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 114-423-837
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Comment: So when you reload the page again. You can debug the further issues.

Comment: There are no issues, the page just states that there is an internal server error.

Comment: Then, please update your code with more code information.

Comment: The code is this:
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

Comment: What you will get on the console. When you reload the page ?'

Comment: The console prints this:
Serving Flask app "main" (lazy loading) * Environment: production WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead. * Debug mode: on * Restarting with windowsapi reloader * Debugger is active! * Debugger PIN: 114-423-837 * Running on 127.0.0.1:5000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)

Comment: After this, The console will give the corresponding information on each page reload something like this. `[28/Jul/2020 16:58:05] "GET /reports/booking-history/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3219`

Comment: I know it should, however it does not.